# Show that $f$ is integrable iff $\sum\limits_k2^k \mu(\lbrace f \ge 2^k \rbrace)$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu X< \infty$ and f is a nonnegative measurable function.

Then $f\in L_1(X) \iff \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^k \mu(\lbrace x\in X : f(x) \ge 2^k \rbrace)<\infty $

To prove this for $\implies$:

I choose $f_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}2^{-k}f$ which converges to $f$. Also it converges with respect to $L_1$ that is $\forall \epsilon$ $\int|f_n-f|d\mu<\epsilon$. Then I have convergence in measure, that is, $\forall\alpha>0$ $\mu(\lbrace x\in X: |f_n(x)-f(x)|\ge \alpha)=0$

But now what should I do to get there? Am I on the right track?

Comment: Isn't convergence in $L_1$ $\int_X |f_n - f| d\mu < \infty$ and not $< \epsilon$ ? Because, you have that integral is finite, but its not necessary that it is arbitrary small.

Comment: @Cortizol what you said is condition for being an element of $L_1$

Comment: As far I know, $f \in L_1(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ iff $f:X \to \mathbf{C}(\text{or } \mathbf{R})$ is measurable and $\int_X |f| \, d\mu < \infty$.

Comment: Exacly, but here what we have it convergence in $L_1$
For reference R G. Bartle The elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure Ch. 6 and 7

Comment: Ah, yes. Silly me. Convergence to zero in $L_1$. My mistake.

Comment: Well actually, here the $f_n$ I defined converges to $f\neq 0$ in $L_1$
Your definition for $f\in L_1$ is true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$f(x)\leqslant1+\sum_{k=0}^\infty2^k\cdot\mathbf 1_{f(x)\geqslant2^k}\leqslant1+2\cdot f(x)$$

Comment: nice inequality.

Comment: A little explaniton please?

Comment: Sure: I suggest to compute the middle side when $f(x)$ is, say, $1$, $2$, $3.9$, $4$ and $4.5$, to see what happens.